# MVVM best practice around view logic in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am trying to get into MVVM and away from the code behind approach in Silverlight, and I want to know the best practices around how to invoke view logic.

I have a very basic page where I have bound a listbox to a collection of domain objects, this is all using MVVM, so when I recieve my data back from the services, I want to fire off an animation and view changes on the screen.

Where/How is the best way to doing this? Silverlight (version 3, BTW) doesnt have triggers does it? I have seen blogs where people seem to be using them, but i think they must be rolling their own? Not sure... anyways, any thoughts ideas here is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think code behind is just fine as long as it only works with the view, i.e. it is concerned only with UI concerns. Don't struggle for no-code-behind when the easier way out is just as correct.

Secondly, of course sometime you need some sort of disconnected communication between your view and view-model (for example, getting multiple selected items from your view into your view-model). For these purposes you could use an aggregator like [MVVMLight](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)'s Messenger, which is both simple and expresses the concept nicely. You can send a message from the view-model and have the view listen for it; also you can send messages from your view (when some events occur) and broadcast them.

MVVMLight also includes some utility classes which make it easy to bind events directly to Commands in your view-model, so that's the easier option in most cases I think.

Comment: I have no issues with code-behind :) I just wanted to know how people handled this situation, code-behind or no code-behind. I know that it would be easy to create an observable type of implementation, where the VM could notify "listeners" (i.e. the view) of changes, that would be simple. I will take a look at the mvvm light toolkit though